# CSS opacity animation changes position?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-animations

Does the CSS animation property when used to change opacity also change the position of an element? If so, what is going on in the DOM that makes that happen, and how can it be offset?

**Context**: I've added a Javascript EventListener to a set of images, which when clicked calls a function that initiates a CSS animation fading the clicked image. A timer is also set that removes a CSS class thereby returning the clicked image from opacity 0 to opacity 1. It all works fine except that the image reappears slightly off to the left and top from where I originally placed it and where I want it to be. The same unwanted effect happens on both Chrome and Safari.

Here's the CSS:

```
.hiddenanimal { 
    animation: animalfade 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animalfade {
    from { opacity: 1; 
    } to {  opacity: 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to be able to answer your question properly (as opposed to just guessing)

Comment: My Javascript adds the hiddenanimal CSS class below, and later removes it:

`.hiddenanimal { 
 animation: animalfade 1s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animalfade {
 from { opacity: 1; 
 } to {  opacity: 0; 
 }
}

Comment: You can edit the question to add the [mcve] - Welcome to StackOverflow - please take the [tour] and check out our section on [ask]

Comment: To answer your question - no. The CSS provided does not alter the image position. I’m guessing there’s something going on in your javascript :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: A CSS animation will only change values you tell it to. In your example:

```
@keyframes animalfade {
  from {opacity: 1;} to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

The only thing that will change is the `opacity`.

If your element is moving then something else is happening and maybe not to the element with the animation.

You ask what is going on in the DOM. Technically: nothing. The CSS values are changing over time, not the DOM.

Having a better example would help others to be able to answer your question better. I have made assumptions and have no idea is my answer is even close to what you want to know. If you can update your question to include some HTML and JavaScript then I can modify my answer.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helps because it made me look for an explanation elsewhere. The problem seems to involve the Javascript. I had used the setAttribute method to add the .hiddenanimal class, without realizing that it would remove my existing class, which had a padding. When I use setAttribute to add back my original class when the timer is called, then the image is back in the position I want it. I also needed to add the same padding amount into `@keyframes animalfade` because otherwise it would jump position a bit at the start of the animation.